# Selenium Tests ant Key events

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, tapestry

I have some problems with my selenium tests on Google Chrome with the key event.

I just used this code :

```
keyDown("//Myselector","a");
```

But the event is not triggered.

Everything is OK when I launch it with jetty. Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Is there any particular reason that you need to use keyDown? Won't a selenium.type() do the same thing for you? I couldn't get keyDown to work for my tests either.

Comment: Because, I use a jQuery plugin, waiting for a keyboard event. And I tried the type method, but my event was not handled.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there seems to be a bug in htmlutils.js triggerKeyEvent() function. The issue in [Selenium's tracking system](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=567) provides a workaround for jQuery users and a fix for the function.